# Argo workflow PermissionDenied error with sso for GetInfo and GetUserInfo methods

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

I am new to Argo and trying to deploy Argo Workflow and Events. I have configured sso with Azure AD but for some reason it's giving me 403 error after sso login. I can see the below errors in my argo server pod logs

```json
{"error":"no service account rule matches","level":"error","msg":"failed to perform RBAC authorization","time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57.684Z"}
{"error":"rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = not allowed","grpc.code":"PermissionDenied","grpc.method":"GetInfo","grpc.service":"info.InfoService","grpc.start_time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57Z","grpc.time_ms":3.009,"level":"warning","msg":"finished unary call with code PermissionDenied","span.kind":"server","system":"grpc","time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57.684Z"}
{"duration":5035421,"level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"","path":"/api/v1/info","size":34,"status":403,"time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57.684Z"}
{"error":"no service account rule matches","level":"error","msg":"failed to perform RBAC authorization","time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57.684Z"}
{"error":"rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = not allowed","grpc.code":"PermissionDenied","grpc.method":"GetUserInfo","grpc.service":"info.InfoService","grpc.start_time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57Z","grpc.time_ms":3.797,"level":"warning","msg":"finished unary call with code PermissionDenied","span.kind":"server","system":"grpc","time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57.684Z"}
{"duration":5566292,"level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"","path":"/api/v1/userinfo","size":34,"status":403,"time":"2023-03-19T07:07:57.685Z"}
```

Below is my argo server sso configuration

```json
  sso:
    clientId:
      name: argo-sso-secrets
      key: client-id
    clientSecret:
      name: argo-sso-secrets
      key: client-secret
    issuer: MY_ISSUER_URL
    redirectUrl: https://argo-workflows.com/oauth2/callback
    rbac:
      enabled: true
  extraArgs:
    - --auth-mode=sso
```

Argo Workflow Version: v3.4.5
Argo workflo helm chart version: 0.22.14

Can someone please point me to what I'm missing here ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you enable
**rbac:
enabled: true**
You have to create aervice account for relation dex or cognito groups with sv account and rbac

I think if you disable rbac it should to be work.